# Removing slashes from column names in estout

Tags: latex, stata

I use the *community-contributed* command `estout` to create a summary statistics table in Stata.

My code displays standard deviations in parentheses below each mean estimate:

```
sysuse auto, clear

eststo clear
estpost summarize price mpg weight
esttab, cells(mean sd(par))

-------------------------
                      (1)

                  mean/sd
-------------------------
price            6165.257
               (2949.496)
mpg               21.2973
               (5.785503)
weight           3019.459
               (777.1936)
-------------------------
N                      74
-------------------------
```

How can I eliminate the slash (`/`), while forcing `mean` and `sd` to display on top of each other?

I would also like to export the results in `LaTeX`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the options below in order to produce the desired outcome:

```
esttab, cells(mean sd(par)) mtitle("mean") collabels("sd") nonumbers

-------------------------
                     mean
                       sd
-------------------------
price            6165.257
               (2949.496)
mpg               21.2973
               (5.785503)
weight           3019.459
               (777.1936)
-------------------------
N                      74
-------------------------
```

For `LaTeX` output, you also need the `tex` option:

```
esttab, cells(mean sd(par)) mtitle("mean") collabels("sd") nonumbers tex

{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{c}}
\hline\hline
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{mean}\\
            &          sd\\
\hline
price       &    6165.257\\
            &  (2949.496)\\
mpg         &     21.2973\\
            &  (5.785503)\\
weight      &    3019.459\\
            &  (777.1936)\\
\hline
\(N\)       &          74\\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
}
```